# Python filter elements contains the same parameters

Tags: python

I have three list of dicts

`renting = [{'id': '92061083359', 'lp': '1', 'title': 'TITLE 1'}, {'id': '94103033254', 'lp': '2', 'title': 'TITLE 3'}, {'id': '92071176944', 'lp': '3', 'title': 'TITLE2'}, {'id': '93022138167', 'lp': '4', 'title': 'TITLE2'}]`

`students = [{'lastname': 'BAJOREK', 'id': '92051048757', 'name': 'JAKUB'}, {'lastname': 'SLOTARZ', 'id': '92051861424', 'name': 'MARIANNA'}, {'lastname': 'WNUK', 'id': '92052033215', 'name': 'SZYMON'}, {'lastname': 'LESKO', 'id': '92052877491', 'name': 'WOJCIECH'}]`

`rooms = [{'id_room': '8', 'id': '92061083359'}, {'id_room': '32', 'id': '94103033254'}, {'id_room': '47', 'id': '93022138167'}, {'id_room': '47', 'id': '92071176944'}]`

I would like to filter this dict to show only this title of books which are the same in the room (id_room).

Output

Room 47 have 2 duplicated books (the same title).

I write some code, but it's not working good

```
house_ids = set(report_dict['id'] for report_dict in report_student)
the_same = []
count = 0
# zliczanie tytulow ktore sa wyporzyczone kilka razy
for b in renting:
    count = 0
    stu = []
    for r in renting:
        if b.get('id') == r.get('title'):
            count += 1
            if count > 1:
                stu.append(r.get('id'))
    the_same.append(stu)

pesel_by_id = []

# sprawdzanie nr pesel w odniesieniu do mieszkania
for l in the_same:

    for pesel in l:
        tmp = []
        for mel in house_ids:
            if mel == pesel:
                tmp.append(mel)
    pesel_by_id.append(tmp)

count = 0

for x in pesel_by_id:
    for y in x:
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter`, which is built into Python:

```
def search(id_room):
    book_id = filter(lambda a: a['id_room'] == id_room, rooms)[0]['id']
    title = filter(lambda a: a['id'] == book_id, renting)[0]['title']
    return len(filter(lambda a: a['title'] == title, renting))

print (search('47'))
```

Comment: Ok, but how to count duplicates in each room?

Comment: I updated the code, it should work now.  If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Comment: I change `a['title']` to `a.get('title')` because interpreter call KeyError: 'title'. I read data from file.

Comment: neli, another problem. When I put the same data on the last places in list function show 1. Eg. `renting = [{'id': '92060863855', 'lp': '1', 'title': 'WSTEP DO INFORMATYKI'},
           {'id': '93013078979', 'lp': '2', 'title': 'W SIECI KOMPUTEROWEJ'},
           {'id': '93091115319', 'lp': '3', 'title': 'MIKROKONTROLERY AVR'},
           {'id': '93112747286', 'lp': '4', 'title': 'AUTOCAD DOBRE PRAKTYKI'},
           {'id': '94030283737', 'lp': '4', 'title': 'AUTOMATYKA II'},
           {'id': '96081771827', 'lp': '4', 'title': 'AUTOMATYKA II'}
           ]`

Comment: You're getting 'IndexError: list index out of range' meaning that there is no results no results.

Comment: No, I put all my sample data https://pastebin.com/cnAfzxFa and result for `search('1')` should return 1, but it's return 4.